# Magento form - how to display input fields on the same row?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have this form:

```
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

    $costsForm = $form->addFieldset('costs', array(
        'legend'    => Mage::helper('starmall_config')->__('Shipping costs')
    ));

    $data = array();

    $costsArr = Mage::helper("starmall_config")->getShippingWeightRateList();

    for ($i=0; $i < count($costsArr); $i++) {
        $data["ship_cost_" . $i . "_from"] = $costsArr[$i]["from"]; 
        $data["ship_cost_" . $i . "_to"] = $costsArr[$i]["to"]; 

        // 1st column
        $costsForm->addField("ship_cost_" . $i . "_from", 'text', array(
            'name'      => "ship_cost_" . $i . "_from",
            'label'     => $costsArr[$i]["label"],
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'style'     => 'width:50px',
            'required'  => true,
        ));

        // 2nd column
        // how to add a new field on the same row in another column 

        // 3rd column
        // how to add a new field on the same row in another column

        // 4th column
        // how to add a new field on the same row in another column
    }
```

It looks like this:
[image]

I want to add multiple input fields on the same row. Can this be done in Magento 1.7 ?

Comment: I needed a quick solution and did not want to fiddle with javascript. So I ended it up just creating all fields on a new row. Until I find a better solution.

Comment: please let me know if you solved this..I also having same problem

Comment: @SatishSojitra sorry no nice fix. I used a regular Magento form with one row per field. I needed a quick solution and did not want to mess with a extra code.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you add fields directly to the form ( e.g. $form->addField(....) )

\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\form\renderer\element.phtml

around line 29:

change:

```
<span class="field-row">
```

into:

```
<span class="field-row <?= $_element->getId();?>">
```

Now you have access to the form row with a class, and you can play with CSS to achieve what you need.

---

2) If you add fields to a form fieldset ( e.g. $fieldset->addField(....) )

- provide parameter "container_id", for example:

  ```
      $fieldset->addField('test_field', 'text', array(
      'name'      => 'test_field',
      'label'     => $this->__('Test field'),
      'required'  => false,
      'disabled'  => false,
      'style'     => 'width:50px;',
      'container_id'  => 'some-row-id'
  ));
  ```

After rendering you will see:

```
<tr id="some-row-id">
```

And now you can play easily with CSS to get what you need.

Kind Regards,
Janusz

Comment: I know this is an old post but how can you possibly use CSS to achieve the result the OP is after?

Answer (score 0):

Hello as Magento actually stores one value per path (see core_config_data table) the only way I can think of to achieve this would be to save your data in json or serialized format, then overwrite the renderer to split the information into separate input fields. even easyer would be to just add some javascript that automatically splits the json to separate inputs and then combines it back toghether on submit so you do not have to edit the models and renderers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setNoSpan() method.
For example:

```
$checkbox = $this->addField('is_enabled', 'checkbox', array(
            'onclick'   => 'this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;',
            'name'      => 'is_enabled',
))->setNoSpan(true);
```

or

```
$checkbox = $this->addField('is_enabled', 'checkbox', array(
            'onclick'   => 'this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;',
            'name'      => 'is_enabled',
            'no_span' => true
        ));
```

You can see usage of this element in follow file:

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/form/renderer/element.phtml

```
<?php $_element = $this->getElement() ?>
<?php if($_element->getNoSpan() !== true): ?>
<span class="field-row">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $_element->getLabelHtml() ?>
<?php echo $_element->getElementHtml() ?>
<?php if($_element->getNoSpan() !== true): ?>
</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```